# How to test immutability and if reducer if pure function in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In multiple places of my app, there're bugs: people wrote reducers that were not pure and also reducers modified existing state by working on existing objects.

Now, before fixing it I would like to write tests that prove that reducers had bugs and modified existing state.

I could do this manually by doing dozens of assertions, but perhaps there's a better way to do it. Are there any matchers / libs that could help me with that in the context on `Jest`?

Comment: Some things to consider / answer before you go any futher - 
1. Do all your reducers follow the same pattern ( have you enforced it by any means ) ?

2. Are you using any immutable helper such as Immutable JS?

3. Do you really want to check your big JS app for reducer immutability, when you can simply check react re-renders and get away with it ?

Comment: Have you find an answer yet @dragonfly? I think this is an excellent question and I cannot wrap my head around how to systematically do it for all reducers. Also, @ShobhitChittora, "get away with it?" it is much more complicated because it means that if an object was mutated in the reducer, react-redux will say it was the same object thus not rendering the component...

Comment: This is an idea: https://gist.github.com/ruffle1986/21091cfbce4e033607ee

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this library: [redux-testkit](https://github.com/wix/redux-testkit), you can easily test the reducers and if some reducer mutates the test will fail. Also can test actions (by thunk) and selectors. Here is an example:

```
  test("when SET_FORM_VALUE, should set formValues", () => {
    const previousState = { formValues: null };
    const fakeFormValues = {
      fakeValue: "fake-value"
    };
    Reducer(reducer)
      .withState(previousState)
      .expect({ type: SET_FORM_VALUE, payload: fakeFormValues })
      .toChangeInState({
        formValues: fakeFormValues
      });
  });
```

Also, you can use another library like [deep-freeze](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze). This one applies the `Object.freeze` deeply. The test raise an error if the object is modified in the method you are testing.

```js
    test("should not be modified", () => {
      const obj = { value: 5 };

      deepFreeze(obj);

      obj.value = 6;
    });
```

[image]